# Deploying Spring Batch jar

Tags: spring-batch

I have created a Runnable Jar file by exporting Spring batch project in eclipse. Now my requirement is deploy this Jar is production type environment. How could I deploy my Spring batch Jar, ?

The Spring batch project Jar is working in " java -jar application.jar". But I have to deploy this Jar file somewhere so that anybody can run it.

Comment: Learn maven; for easy project is not so hard

Answer (score 1):

1) Create the executable jar of your project.
2) Place it in unix server i.e. if your production env is unix box.
3) Create a shell script which will call the main method of your spring batch.
 e.g.

```
java cp $CP -Xms256m -Xmx512m $MAIN_CLASS 

where 
$CP is classpath  containg all required jars
$MAIN_CLASS is the fully qualified name of your main class
```

Now any one can execute this shell script if have access to it on unix box:

```
./batch-execute.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the template projects that Spring Batch provides, you can package your job into an zip file that contains the executable jar, the dependent libraries, and execution scripts for both Windows and *nix environments.  To do this, execute the `$ mvm clean package` command from the command line.  In the target directory of your project, you'll find the zip files I am talking about.

Comment: My ultimate need is data movement from say LocalFile system to MySQL DB using Spring Batch. Will it be good enough to create a spring project and export it as runnable Jar. In deployment perspective what about by using shell script to run the JAR. I am sitting behind a firewall where Maven is not working even after configured proxy. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If you can't use maven to get the dependencies, you can download the full releases here: http://docs.spring.io/downloads/nightly/release-download.php?project=BATCH .  We don't supply zip files with the dependencies so you'll still need to figure out how to download those as well without maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web project, define a REST Controller, import your jar, context, job configs, etc. In the controller define a method which will launch the Job. From the browser or the REST client call the controller operation to launch your job.